# Python kivy minimum system requirements

Tags: python, kivy

How much is the minimum system requirements?
Or how much resources it typically uses
M using Windows 7 
I have a old computer with 2.4ghz cpu 1gb ram will it be possible to run kivy ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only requirement whatsoever is **GPU** and at least **OpenGL (ES) 2.0+**, the rest highly depends on what Python packages and C-extensions you use. If your OS's recommended requirements are satisfied, Kivy should work just fine for built-in stuff and more. Kivy (officially, but it runs flawlessly) doesn't support Win XP, so the next one is Vista:

- 1 GHz 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) CPU
- 1 GB of RAM
- 128 MB of graphics memory

Those should be *"optimal"*, but Kivy also works on Raspberry Pi, so the minimal CPU freq **could be** around **~900MHz**.

Basically, if you want to lower the requirements as much as possible, get a virtual machine and start dropping the RAM and VRAM amount until the [Kivy Showcase](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/showcase) and [animation demo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/animation/animate.py) start to lag or freeze, you should get at least approximate value of how much RAM and VRAM is used with your OpenGL version for:

- Python interpreter
- Kivy deps
- Kivy itself

Also, a basic app has **~30MB RAM usage**, because you need to initialise the whole interpreter, import deps & kivy, create window and more stuff that happen under the hood.